# PyParsing Or operator that unwinds until match found

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

```
import pyparsing as pp

one = pp.Literal("ab").setName("one")
two = pp.Literal("aba").setName("two")
combined = (one | two) + "e"
combined.setName("combined")

print(combined.parseString("abae", parseAll=True))
```

In English, I'd expect "abae" to match given the "valid if ab or aba followed by e".  Wondering how to do the same using the library.  i.e. define rules where the "or" matches in a way that tries all options.

Understanding that the pipe operator indicates match first, I'm not surprised that the above example fails.  I considered caret, but there are also situations, like "abe" in the above example, where caret does not meet my needs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `combined = (one ^ two) + "e"` would not work for "abe"?  You could also try `combined = oneOf("ab aba") + "e"`.

Comment: Sorry, Paul.  Abe was a horrible and incorrect example.  But I'm sure you can imagine a more complex set of rules with multiple depths of or statements where either caret or pipe would exclude some results.  I'm reading up on oneOf, thanks for that and the quick response.  Happy holidays.